# Cannot read property 'call' of undefined while updating reagent version from 0.6.0 to 0.8.1

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I was updating the version of reagent for 0.6.0 to 0.8.1 and got the error `Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`. The error is being thrown by the `create-class` method in reagent.

Tried adding `cljs.create-react-class` but that didn't work.

Comment: I have been using 0.8.1 for months w/o problem.  Perhaps the change has caused it to exercise your code in a different way or a new area...?

Comment: You might need to clean out and do a completely fresh build. Make sure all the previous compilation is gone.

Answer (score 0):

For people landing from search:

I encountered this issue, also during a migration from reagent 0.6.0 to 0.8.1, but I doubt this is version specific.

Working with https://github.com/Gonzih/cljs-electron as a base, at some point, I am able to get the app into a strange state and reagent stops loading correctly. One working method that recovers from the strange state and got `cljsbuild` working again was by deleting everything that was a compilation output, in particular those in `.gitignore` (`target`, `resources/public/js`, etc.). After removing those files and rerunning `lein cljsbuild once` the application worked again.